# How to make tab view have a folder-tab look

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I wanted to make my tabs look like a folder-filed tabs like this:

[image: Tab View]

and since I'm using android's default navigation type as "Fixed tabs + swipe," my tabs look like this:

[image]

I have been searching but nothing comes close to what I wanted to see.

Should there be changes for layout or the class itself?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.